# Failed to create ClusterRole for kube-lego

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I did this example https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/tree/master/examples/gce , then failed to create ClusterRole kube-lego.

The error is:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "k8s/kube-lego/hoge.yaml": clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-lego" is forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges: [PolicyRule{Resources:["pods"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["pods"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["services"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["create"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["services"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["services"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["delete"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["services"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["update"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["endpoints"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["create"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["endpoints"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["endpoints"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["delete"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["endpoints"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["update"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["ingresses"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["ingresses"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["update"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["ingresses"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["create"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["ingresses"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["ingresses"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["patch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["ingresses"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["delete"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["ingresses"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["endpoints"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["endpoints"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["create"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["endpoints"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["update"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["secrets"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["secrets"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["create"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["secrets"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["update"]}] user=&{myemail@gmail.com  [system:authenticated] map[]} ownerrules=[PolicyRule{Resources:["selfsubjectaccessreviews" "selfsubjectrulesreviews"], APIGroups:["authorization.k8s.io"], Verbs:["create"]} PolicyRule{NonResourceURLs:["/api" "/api/*" "/apis" "/apis/*" "/healthz" "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1" "/swagger.json" "/swaggerapi" "/swaggerapi/*" "/version"], Verbs:["get"]}] ruleResolutionErrors=[]
```

I tried on 1.8.6-gke.0, 1.8.7-gke.0 and 1.9.2-gke.0.

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As commented in [`kube-lego` issue 225](https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/issues/225#issuecomment-313412762):

> Turns out the error I was receiving in an known issue with GKE 1.6. I resolved by following this article:
>
> ### get current google identity

```
$ gcloud info | grep Account
Account: [myname@example.org]
```

> ### grant cluster-admin to your current identity

```
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding myname-cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=myname@example.org
Clusterrolebinding "myname-cluster-admin-binding" created
```

For the actual RBAC to define, see [issue 99](https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/issues/99)

It refers to [**Adds official RBAC rules**](https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/commit/22e3451ca286276d0e4746522b16dd984fb07b9a), which applies the right settings:

```
# RBAC objects
kubectl apply -f lego/service-account.yaml
kubectl apply -f lego/cluster-role.yaml
kubectl apply -f lego/cluster-role-binding.yaml
```

Comment: This works for a user account (like `myuser@gmail.com`) but it doesn't work from a GCE VM using a default service account like `k8s-deployment@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com` -- the clusterrolebinding is created just fine, but using it won't allow me to create a new role.

Comment: @Bosh Strange: can you ask a new question for this case?

Answer (score 2):

Your Google account email from `gcloud info | grep Account` may not work, but I sorted this out.

Go to [Stackdriver Logging](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer), select appropriate kubernetes cluster and error log level.

Apply the next advanced filter (change apropriate fields):

```
resource.type="k8s_cluster"
resource.labels.location="europe-west1-b"
resource.labels.cluster_name="your-cluster-name"
severity>=ERROR
protoPayload.resourceName="rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/clusterroles/prometheus-operator"
```

And you'll find errors like:

```
k8s.io create prometheus-operator 20456435270447878856446 {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code": ...
```

Next, you need to copy that long numbered `principalEmail`. Paste it in `clusterrolebinding` command, as a user key:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding 20456435270447878856446-cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=20456435270447878856446
```

and you'll be able to create prometheus-operator cluster role.

Comment: Dude, you're my hero. Thank you!